# Modal Bootstrap - Source Code is different than info rendered by Chrome

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm doing an e-commerce project and I rant into an issue. I'm using Bootstrap and Django. I apologize for the long question

I basically have a loop that runs through my list of products in the database and lists them. It's a table. Each row is a new product and the cells are specific info about the product. The last cell creates a little modal to edit the current information on the project. The information is being passed correctly through the loop, but on Chrome's rendering I see the information for product one listed in all products.

This is what the table looks like:

[image: For context, this is what the table looks like]

This is what my loop to generate the table looks like:

```
<tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{% static product.main_picture %}" style="width: 100px;">
        </td>
        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.inventory_count}}</td>
        <td>{{product.sold_count}}</td>
        <td>
        <!-- Button trigger edit modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">Edit</button>
         <!-- Edit product Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit the product</h5>
                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                         </div>
                     <div class="modal-body">
                     <!-- Form to edit product -->
                     <form method='post' action='/dashboard/products/update'>
                     {% csrf_token %}
                         <div class="form-group">
                             <label>Name:</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" value="{{product.name}}">
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Picture:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control-file" name="product_picture" value="{{product.main_picture}}">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Description:</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_desc" value="{{product.description}}">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Inventory Count</label>
                              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="inventory_count" value="{{product.inventory_count}}">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Price</label>
                               <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" value="{{product.price}}">
                            </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
                         </form>
                         <!-- End of form -->
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

This is what the source code looks like for Chrome:

https://gist.github.com/amandademetrio/3f1fdc68609c9c0c3546352d3b697286

It works perfectly on the source code, but here's what shows when I click in every product:

[image]

Information of the first product is shown for every product.

Sorry about the long question. Did anyone run into a similar issue and could help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the same id (`editModal`) for all your product rows which is not allowed. When you click the `Edit` button (with `data-target="#editModal"`), Javascript looks for an element with an id of `editModal` and uses the first one it finds.

Change your `Edit` button code to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" 
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal-{{ forloop.counter }}">Edit</button>
```

and modify your modal `div` to match the same `id`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal-{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

If you check out the generated source code now, you will see that there are unique ids such as `editModal-0`, `editModal-1`, `...` for each row.